# Travis.yml failing with minimalistic contents?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have the current `travis.yml` on my Github:

```
# see http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/php/ for more hints
language: php

# list any PHP version you want to test against
php:
  # aliased to a recent 5.4.x version
  - 5.4
  # aliased to a recent 5.5.x version
  - 5.5
```

All my jobs keep failing, but with a minimalistic build, i Cannot see why it fails.. As Travis doesn't exactly have the best information.. Here is the last few chunks of my logs:

Job 9.1:

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/SlayerSolutions/Authentication.git SlayerSolutions/Authentication

Cloning into 'SlayerSolutions/Authentication'...

remote: Counting objects: 128, done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.

remote: Total 128 (delta 55), reused 83 (delta 15)

Receiving objects: 100% (128/128), 19.17 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (55/55), done.

$ cd SlayerSolutions/Authentication
git.2

$ git checkout -qf 1df78d018dbe8a81e66490e90012229adcff7af8

$ phpenv global 5.4

$ php --version

PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 28 2013 11:14:20)

Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

$ composer --version

Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.16/bin/composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.

Composer version 7755564962718189d5d7d9fdee595283c8f032b7

$ phpunit

PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage: phpunit [switches] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]

phpunit [switches] <directory>

--log-junit <file> Log test execution in JUnit XML format to file.
 ...Bla,bla,bla

The command "phpunit" exited with 2.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

and Job 9.2:

Is the same and ends with:

```
The command "phpunit" exited with 2.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

So, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any non-zero exit code of the scripts you run with Travis are considered a failure.
Your minimalistic `.travis.yml` does not specify a build script, therefore the default build script for PHP is run, which is `phpunit` ([see also the documentation](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/php/)).

As you don't have a phpunit.xml in your repository, there is basically nothing to run for Travis. This leads to the failing build.

It really depends what you want to do with Travis, but either you configure your repository according to the default or define a script to execute when running the build like this:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.4
  - 5.5

script: ./build.sh
```

Then you can specify whatever you want in the `build.sh` to be executed when running build.

You may need to insure that `./build.sh` is executable which you can do with

```
before_install:
  - chmod +x build.sh
```

You can also make the script `bash build.sh` or `sh build.sh`.

Comment: What should be written in build.sh file ?

Comment: @VivekChaturvedi: whatever you want to test/build on the CI server. For PHP this could be e.g. `phpunit` or maybe you want to check a code style using `phpcs`. This totally depends on your project and needs.