# Does Travis CI Check more than one .travis.yml file?

Tags: phpunit, travis-ci

I'm just starting with Continuous Integration using [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org).

I have this file at the TLD of my repo:

```
sudo: false
language: php
php:
  - '7.1'
```

This is how Travis CI sees my config:

```
{
  "os": "linux",
  "php": "7.1",
  "dist": "trusty",
  "sudo": false,
  "group": "stable",
  "language": "php",
}
```

Why is the build [failing](https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/377403989/log.txt) with a phpunit error? Could it be because of another `.travis.yml` file within the repo?

```
Network availability confirmed.
...edited for brevity...
git.checkout
0.34s$ git clone  ...edited for brevity...
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.11 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2017 16:25:55) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
...edited for brevity...
$ composer --version
Composer version 1.6.5 2018-05-04 11:44:59
0.15s$ phpunit
PHPUnit 6.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [options] <directory>
...edited for brevity...

The command "phpunit" exited with 2.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

I'm not sure where to look next.

Comment: No. But it includes certain default values, which you are seeing.

Comment: I see now that there needs to be something for Travis to run: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248380/2223106

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phpunit` exits with an error because you haven't told `phpunit` where to look for your tests. Typically you would do this by placing `phpunit.xml` in the base directory of your repo. Among other things, `phpunit.xml` tells `phpunit` which directory contains your tests.

Your `phpunit.xml`should contain something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Your application name">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Replace `./tests/` with the relative path to the folder containing your test files.

To test out your configuration, run `phpunit` while in the base directory of your repo. You should see the same result that Travis CI does.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build), "Travis CI uses `.travis.yml` file in the root of your repository to learn about your project and how you want your builds to be executed."

It wants *something* to run and defaults to running phpunit, which will fail without at least one test to run.

So for a placeholder build one could create a bash script in the same directory as the `.travis.yml` file, make it executable and point to it like this:

```
sudo: false
language: php
php:
  - '7.1'

before_install:
  - chmod +x build.sh

script: ./build.sh
```

This is a "build" script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo This is a placeholder.
```